# AWS IoT JITPovisioning template with Fn::Join

Tags: aws-iot

I am trying to add registrationConfig for my CA certificate in AWS IoT. I would like to do some manipulation of data for Thing attributes. But I can't seem to get that JITP to work if the template body has Fn::Join in it.

Following are extract of the template body (string unescaped for reading purpose)

NOT working:

```
"Resources": {
  "thing": {
    "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
    "Properties": {
      "ThingName": {
        "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName"
      },
      "ThingTypeName" :  "w2-device",
      "ThingGroups" : ["w2-devices"],
      "AttributePayload": {
        "location": {
          "Fn::Join":["",["ThingPrefix_",{"Ref":"SerialNumber"}]]
        },
        "organization": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Organization"
        },
        "version": "w2",
        "country": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

In the above when I have `Fn::Join` in AttributePayload/location it fails to create the Thing during JITP. I don't see any errors in CloudWatch either.

Working:

```
"Resources": {
  "thing": {
    "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
    "Properties": {
      "ThingName": {
        "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName"
      },
      "ThingTypeName" :  "w2-device",
      "ThingGroups" : ["w2-devices"],
      "AttributePayload": {
        "location": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::StateName"
        },
        "organization": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Organization"
        },
        "version": "w2",
        "country": {
          "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country"
        }
      }
    }
},
```

Note: I have also asked this in [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=934186#934186) but without any answer there yet.

Comment: What happens if you have `SerialNumber` in the parameters and/or use the full reference `AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber` ?  How close is your template to the example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html#fleet-provision-template ?

Comment: Very similar to that example in that page. Ref to AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber works.

Comment: I have added an answer that describes the reasoning behind why `AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber` works

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning templates for JITP define a set of parameters beginning with `AWS::IoT::Certificate`.

The `AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber` parameter should be used instead of just `SerialNumber` in the attribute payload. e.g.

```
"AttributePayload": {
    "location": {
      "Fn::Join":["",["ThingPrefix_",{"Ref":"AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber"}]]
    },
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jit-provisioning.html lists the defined parameters for JITP as:

> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::Organization
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::OrganizationalUnit
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::DistinguishedNameQualifier
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::StateName
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber
> - AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id

The `SerialNumber` examples in the AWS documentation (without the `AWS::IoT::Certificate` prefix are used for the [Bulk Registration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html#bulk-template-example) process.